# How to write jQuery code in Twig file : Symfony2

Tags: jquery, symfony

I want to validate the DatePicker fields in a Twig file with the jQuery validation. The same code works fine in core PHP but not in the twig file.

I wrote something like this in twig.html file:

```
{% block javascripts %}
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://kylemitofsky.com/libraries/libraries/bootstrap-datepicker.js">    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var nowTemp = new Date();
  var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(),           nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

var checkin = $('#from').datepicker({
    onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        checkout.setValue(newDate);
    }
    checkin.hide();
    $('#to')[0].focus();
}).data('datepicker');
var checkout = $('#to').datepicker({
    onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    checkout.hide();
}).data('datepicker');
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is the form:

```
<div class="span4">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label >Journey Date </label>
       {{ form_widget(Form.dateMin,{'attr':{'class':'datepicker span5','id':'from'} }) }} {{  form_errors(Form.dateMin) }}
        To
       {{ form_widget(Form.dateMax,{'attr':{'class':'datepicker span5','id':'to'} }) }} {{  form_errors(Form.dateMax) }}
           </div>
     </div>
```

What wrong i am doing it is not executing. #NEWBIEW

Comment: Try adding console.log('aaa'); at the begging of the javascripts block and look in your browser "Console". If it not appears that will mean that you didn't load blocks properly.

Comment: @MichalOlszowski thanks, working now :)

Comment: What was wrong ? ;-)

Comment: i was already having one bootstrap-datepicker.js file in folder and was trying to fetch another one from this url, so may be some javascript conflicts were there.. :)

Comment: Yep. If you declare same javascript function twice there is an error. And then all javascripts just won't work. Maybe you could make an answer for your question with problem solution. It will be nice for someone having the same issue in the future.

Comment: The problem with the above code is that the form_widget 'id' value is defined in incorrect level. The id value shouldn't be inside 'attr' but rather on the same level [see symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#reference-form-twig-variables). I.e. the form input didn't get the id value that you intended and hence the jquery selector didn't find anything...

Comment: @ejuhjav: yes this may also be the problem, later on i deleted the id value and it worked fine..